# cable spec: differential characteristic impedance

Tags: cables, differential, characteristic-impedance

I am hunting around for a cable with twisted-shielded pair conductors with the correct differential characteristic impedance for RS-485 (120 ohm)

Most of the cable spec sheets for cables with twisted shielded pair just say "Characteristic Impedance = ... " (here is an example: http://www.alphawire.com/Home/Products/Cable/Alpha-Essentials/Communication-and-Control-Cable/6365?device=pdf)

Is this referring to the differential impedance of the two conductors or the impedance of a single conductor?

Comment: A single conductor can't have a differential impedance. Differential implies a difference between two things.

Comment: The spec sheet I am looking at is for a twisted-shielded pair, not a single conductor. I will modify the question to make that more clear.

Comment: It is referring to the `transmission line` impedance. A twisted pair is a balanced line. Google [transmission line](https://www.google.com/search?q=transmission+line) for more information. It takes into account that both wires *are* the transmission line. 120 ohms is pretty common for twisted pairs. I'm surprised that your link specs 75 ohms.

Comment: @lakeweb, differential impedance of a twisted pair is a function of ratio between conductor diameter and insulation jacket thickness/dielectric constant. For example, Belden makes cables with 52-Ohm characteristic impedance, and even 36-Ohm., https://catalog.belden.com/techdata/EN/82723_techdata.pdf

Comment: HI @Ali Chen, Thanks, yes, I know. I had cat5 in my head and now that I've checked, I see the nominal spec is 100 ohms. For his app, all other things being perfect the SWR from 75 ohms to 120 ohms is 1.6. So only ~5% loss.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the 6365 Alphawire for the connection: while there are 5 twisted pairs, the pairs are not shielded individually. You might have unwanted interference. Better use [Belden 9842](https://catalog.belden.com/techdata/EN/9842_techdata.pdf), 120-Ohms. But it has common shield.
If 1-pair cable, it has 120 Ohms in one shield..

For RS-422 (100 Ohm) there is Belden 8162, with individually-shielded pairs.

I am sure if you search deeper, you will find 120-Ohm individually-shielded  multi-conductor cable.

CORRECTION: since the RS-485 is supposed to be completely balanced, the cross-talk is very diminished, which allows to use non-individually shielded twisted pairs. The classic cable for two full-duplex links is Belden 3109A, pictured in TI guide.